# I want to display the creado_por field of my database as a string

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-backpack

My Database stores the `creado_por` field as `INT` for improvement reasons and I want to display it as a string for my CRUD.

The User once is logged in, has an attribute called `"nombre_completo"` and I want to show that attribute in the customer view of my CRUD. It is currently being displayed as the ID as you can see:

This is how my model looks:

```
public function obtenerCreadoPor()
{
    //dd($this->creado_por);
    if($this->creado_por->user('nombre_completo'))
    {
        return  '<b>' .$this->creado_por.'<b/>';
    }
}
```

And this is how my relationship looks:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}
```

Could you help me to figure out how to display the `nombre_completo` attribute instead of the ID?

Regards.

Comment: `$this->creado_por->user('nombre_completo')` you are passing a parameter but your method signature does not have a parameter : `public function user()``?

Comment: Ohhh thank you! WHat should I write then?

Comment: What field(s) in the user do you need?

Comment: The name which is stored as nombre_completo. I did that this way but it is worn g because I need to do it directly from the ID:

Comment: //        ComprasNotificacionCancelacion::create([
//            'nombre' => $request->nombre,
//            'correo' => $request->correo,
//            'creado_por' => $user->nombre_completo
//        ]);

Comment: Can you add your migrations to your question?

Comment: No I can´t, we  want to do that once the project is done

Comment: What is the field you want to get in what model? your question is very unclear.

Comment: The thing is that the DB has a relationship to display the ID number in the column creado_por. I want to know how can I display the full name of the logged user instead of the ID, while the ID is being stored in the DB. So DB column must contain an INT value instead of a string which is the ID of the current logged user, and the column of the curd should display the attribute nombre_completo of the user instead of the ID.

Comment: You can obtain the current logged user by: `Auth::user()` and get his field by: `Auth::user()->nombre_completo` in your controller.

Comment: It did not work :( I think it has something to be with the model. How something so easy can be so hard omg.

Comment: Can you provide the database fields of the `user`?

Comment: The only one I{m able to use and share is nombre_completo, the rest are for enterprise use only since they containtr address, etc.

Comment: the field `nombre_completo` is it in the user table?

Comment: Yes it is. If i try to display it, Laravel throws the error telling me that column is an INT value, and I{m trying to display a string

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `User ID` you can get the `nombre_completo` attribute by using the User Model:

```
$user = User::find($this->creado_por);

if ($user) {
    return $user->nombre_completo;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is correct, but its being stored as an INT thats why the ID is shown. Is there a way to show another attribute in string while being saved as an INT?